# I'm using a program to analyse my Java code and I don't understand the error or how to fix it

Tags: java, encoding

I'm using the FindBug program from Maryland University and it gives me this error.

I've tested my code on numerous platforms and it works, so why is this code bad-practice, and what can I do to improve it?

[image: Screenshot of code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's telling you the encoding (how the string is turned into bytes) isn't specified.

If you write a text file in Turkey, and load it up in Uzbekistan then you might get different results.  Instead (for example) you could specify the encoding directly by converting the string to bytes yourself using a specified encoding (see [String.getBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29) for an example).

Comment: Ah I see, but is this ever realistically going to be a problem? Presumably there will be no computers nowadays which don't understand Unicode and ANSI, which presumably the default encoder will be one of these.

Comment: It's not that they don't understand the same encodings, it's that two different computers may have a different default.  I believe the defaults are based on the system locale.

Comment: @Geesh_SO *Never* ever rely on what the default for something is. It *will* come to haunt you every time. Sometimes sooner, sometimes later. But it will.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem.  Pick an encoding.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the charset

you can use an[OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)

```
fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),charset);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File%29) documentation: "The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify these values yourself, construct an OutputStreamWriter on a FileOutputStream."

It can be considered bad practice to depend on default character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), instead of `FileWriter`. Which can be wrapped using the [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter), which [allows you to pass an encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter) in the constructor.

Or else, as said by Jeff, the data won't load correctly.

#### [Example](http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch03s03.html)

```
OutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");  
OutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);  
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(bout, "UTF-8");
```