# Not writing in Unicode when exported

Tags: java, file, unicode, printwriter

So I have a programm that is supposed to write text, which uses unicode, to a file. Everythhing works when I do it through Eclipse, but not when exxported. Here is what it looks like when I do it through Eclipse:

> Все товары:  Ted   По цене:   100руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По
>   цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп
>   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп 
>   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб
>
> Проданные товары:  Ted   По цене:   100руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб
>   Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене:
>   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене: 
>   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене:   10руб Дерп   По цене: 
>   10руб
>
> Не проданные товары:
>
> Всего пренесенно: 11 Кол-во проданно: 11 Кол-во не проданно: 0
>   Выручка: 200руб

And this is what it looks like when I do it from a built jar:

> ??? ??????:
>
> ????????? ??????:  Ted   ?? ????:   100??? ????   ?? ????:   10???
>   ????   ?? ????:   10??? ????   ?? ????:   10??? ????   ?? ????:
>   10??? ????   ?? ????:   10??? ????   ?? ????:   10??? ????   ?? ????: 
>   10??? ????   ?? ????:   10??? ????   ?? ????:   10??? ????   ?? ????: 
>   10???
>
> ?? ????????? ??????:
>
> ????? ??????????: 11 ???-?? ????????: 11 ???-?? ?? ????????: 0
>   ???????: 200???

Here is my code:

```
public void writeToFile(Purchase purchase, String dir) throws Exception {
        file = new File(dir);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        printer.println(purchase.getName() + "   По цене:   "
                + purchase.getPrice() + "руб");
        Timer timer = new Timer();
    }

    public void writeFooter(List<Purchase> list) throws Exception {

        int amountSold = 0;
        int amountNotSold = 0;

        int moneyRecieved = 0;

        if (file == null) {
            file = new File(dir);
        }
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        openStreams();

        printer.println("Все товары: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
            writeToFile(list.get(i), dir);
        }

        printer.println();
        printer.println("Проданные товары: ");

        for (int i = 0; i <= list.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (list.get(i).isSold()) {
                writeToFile(list.get(i), dir);
                amountSold++;
                moneyRecieved += list.get(i).getPrice();
            }
        }
        printer.println();
        printer.println("Не проданные товары: ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= list.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (!list.get(i).isSold()) {
                writeToFile(list.get(i), dir);
                amountNotSold++;
            }
        }



        printer.println();
        printer.println("Всего пренесенно: " + list.size());
        printer.println("Кол-во проданно: " + amountSold);
        printer.println("Кол-во не проданно: " + amountNotSold);
        printer.println("Выручка: " + moneyRecieved + "руб");

        closeStreams();
}
```

Comment: set the charset when creating the printer

Comment: Whenever doing any kind of Input/Output, you always need to specify a character set or else it will be automatically decided for you. When using beyond ASCII characters, the automatic/default values will inevitably lead to trouble with high chances. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864878/im-using-a-program-to-analyse-my-java-code-and-i-dont-understand-the-error-or the tool he used ensured that he won't do the same mistake you did.

Answer (score 1):

In the following the encoding "UTF-8" can be left out, and then the current platform encoding is used: `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`.

```
PrintWriter printer = new Printer(
        new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

Also pay attention that the editor encoding and the javac compiler encoding are the same; if you want to pass on the sources. Maybe explicitly set them to UTF-8 in the IDE too.